# Passing collection object from Java Code using Async API's to JasperReports Server using JRXML

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I tried passing collection object from Java code to jrxml, but the jrxml collection object size is showing zero.

Java Code

```
ReportExecutionRequest request = new ReportExecutionRequest();
ReportParameter parameter2 = new ReportParameter();
parameter2.setName("EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID");

List<String> values2 = new ArrayList<String>();

values2.add("1");
values2.add("3");
values2.add("4");
values2.add("10");

parameter2.setValues(values2);

ReportParameters parameters = new ReportParameters();
List<ReportParameter> reportParameters = new ArrayList<ReportParameter>();

reportParameters.add(parameter2);
parameters.setReportParameters(reportParameters);
```

JRXML :

```
<parameter name="EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID" class="java.util.Collection"/>
```

Also, in case string is getting passed using the same java code above, and passing comma separated string and tokenize it in jrxml using Variable doesnt work.

```
<variable name="CatId" class="java.util.Collection">
   <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID}.split(",")]]/>
</variable>
```

Comment: What does it mean: `Collection.split(",")`? The `EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID` is Collection, not the String ....

Comment: Next time, you should edit your post. It is not necessary to delete the old post and create the new one. This code is not relevant too ..

Comment: Try printing the contents of `$P{EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID}` in a text field in your report:
 `<textField>
  <reportElement x="445" y="10" width="100" height="30"/>
  <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
 </textField>`

If this is null or empty, either the parameter is empty or your code doesn't work. If on the other hand you can see a value, you just need to iterate through the values.

Comment: @Alex: Collection.split(",") is used in jrxml when I am passing the string through java code

Comment: I need these parameters for the where clause in sql query. When I am passing the arrayList through java code its coming empty. I need to render the values and create a fusion chart using them.

Comment: I have tried using List but the parameter is still coming empty.

Comment: <parameter name="EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID1" class="java.util.List">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1","2","3"}))]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <queryString>
  <![CDATA[select * from exception_category_lkp where ($X{IN,EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID, EXCEPTION_CATEGORY_ID1} )]]>
 </queryString>

Comment: I am facing similar issue as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597471/async-jasper-report-gives-all-data-when-changing-parameter-name